# Ruby show html tag as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have got a Rails API which is displaying some data as JSON. The response looks good when a user enters plaintext. But when I add html tags or special characters like "" into the input, it converts them to unicode chars. I would like to render the entire thing as string, no matter what the user adds. I have tried using `to_s` but that still doesn't convert those bits into string.

```
 result.each do |row|
      i = row["i"].to_s
      j = row["j"].to_s
      obj[i][j] = {}
      obj[i][j]["name"] = row["name"].to_s
  end

Given: <p>name</p>
Output :\u003cp\u003ename\u003c/p\u003e
Expected output: <p>name</p>
```

Comment: Not sure why it returns Unicode characters. Have your tried forcing encoding to UTF-8 ? Also, I'm thinking about using `raw(<String>)` or  `<String>.html_safe`

Comment: @Sumak yeah that shows the same result actually. Doesn't parse it to html tags

Comment: I don't get how you think you're going to be able to transmit `"`  in JSON without escaping it as it is a reserved character? This smells like a X&Y question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are displaying data as JSON. That is what those chars look like as a JSON string.

```rb
'<p>name</p>'.to_json
=> "\"\\u003cp\\u003ename\\u003c/p\\u003e\""
JSON.parse "\"\\u003cp\\u003ename\\u003c/p\\u003e\""
=> "<p>name</p>"
```